# Как вывести кол-во значений в окне на кнопку?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли вывести кол-во значений находящихся в БД на кнопку. То есть сделать что-то типо уведомлений.
Задача такова: по истечению срока в БД одно значение меняется на другое, потом начинается проверка на это значение и идёт подсчёт кол-ва таких значений. Потом в поле самой кнопки должно выводится число, обозначающее кол-во этих значений. Если это возможно, то, пожалуйста, скиньте ссылку с туториалом или пример

Comment: Что конкретно у вас вызвало затруднения? Если нужно просто вывести значение на кнопку, то `button['text'] = str(x)`

Comment: Затруднения в том, что хотелось бы число в кружок вывести. Ну или как-то отделить от основного текста кнопки

Comment: Тогда формировать картинку (например с помощью библиотеки pillow) и выводить в кнопку.